# Matplotlib bbox_inches='tight' adjust only height

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to reduce the whitespace around my figures but without decreasing the figure width. In the example below I would generate a figure of specific width and height but size the axis is equal (which I would like to maintain) the resulting plot contains a lot of whitespace on both the top and the bottom. Saving the figure using `bbox_inches='tight'` reduces this whitespace but also cuts sometimes on some of the width which I would like to avoid. Any ideas how I would be able to adjust the height to match the axis without influencing the width?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,68,35)
y=np.linspace(0,34,35)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10 * (Z1 - Z2)
Z = np.ma.array(Z)
print Z.shape
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=400)
ax=(fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal'))


CS = plt.contourf(x, y, Z, 10,cmap=plt.cm.bone)

plt.show()
```

Below please find the figure (white background) placed over a brown surface
to better appreciate its extent with respect to the image plotted inside the figure/

[image]

Comment: You have `plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2), dpi=400)` that amounts to requiring a square canvas, you have `ax=(fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal'))` that requires that the scales of the `x` and `y` axes are the same and you don't want the white space around your figure...do you realize that if you put a rectangle, wider than taller, in a square container you _necessarily_ end with vertical white space around your plot?

Comment: Which is why I am asking, if there is a way to only fix the figure width... I do realize that the way it is done above does not work to achieve what I want to do... hence, the question

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`fig.subplots_adjust()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) with the `top` and `bottom` arguments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

fig.subplots_adjust(top=X,bottom=Y) # Set X and Y to suit your needs
```

You can also control the width using `left` and `right` if you need to.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks a lot but thats not quite what I was looking for I did however edit my question as I realized that I probably didn't pose it clearly enough.